# How to check whether android device supports OIS or EIS for camera2 or cameraX video stabilization

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am using Java for android and I could not find any examples of how to check whether an android device supports OIS/EIS video stabilization for cameraX/Camera2.

```
Camera2CameraControl camera2CameraControl =
            Camera2CameraControl.from(camera.getCameraControl());
    CaptureRequestOptions captureRequestOptions =
            new CaptureRequestOptions.Builder()
                    .setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON)
                    .build();
    camera2CameraControl.setCaptureRequestOptions(captureRequestOptions);


Camera2CameraControl camera2CameraControl =
            Camera2CameraControl.from(camera.getCameraControl());
    CaptureRequestOptions captureRequestOptions =
            new CaptureRequestOptions.Builder()
                    .setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE, CameraMetadata.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON)
                    .build();
    camera2CameraControl.setCaptureRequestOptions(captureRequestOptions);
```

I used both of the codes above separately but I did not see a difference. So I suspect that the device that i am using does not support both EIS and OIS but I have to check.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the availability information from cameraCharacterstics

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#CONTROL_AVAILABLE_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODES